# Instruction disassembly for ARM

Tags: gdb, arm, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I just setup a raspberry pi machine and tried reverse engineering the following piece of code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
printf("this is a test\n");
}
```

For the most part the following disassembly in gdb seemed to make sense.

```
   0x000083c8 <+0>: push    {r11, lr}
   0x000083cc <+4>: add r11, sp, #4
   0x000083d0 <+8>: ldr r0, [pc, #8]    ; 0x83e0 <main+24>
   0x000083d4 <+12>:    bl  0x82ec <puts>
   0x000083d8 <+16>:    mov r0, r3
   0x000083dc <+20>:    pop {r11, pc}
   0x000083e0 <+24>:    andeq   r8, r0, r4, asr r4
```

1. However, I fail to understand why the instruction at `0x000083e0` exists. Is that instruction even a part of the main function? Wouldn't the value that was pushed in at 0x000083c8 be popped out into pc, immediately transferring control over to some other location?
2. Also I tried setting a breakpoint at 0x000083e0 -- I seem to be getting a very strange SEGFAULT. Why would that be?

Answer (score 3):

When this function is called (i.e. when execution begins at instruction `0x000083c8`), the link register (LR) should already contain the return address.  Fast-forward to `0x000083d8`: the *puts* function's return result is placed in R0 in accordance with the ARM C calling convention ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention#ARM), [link](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042e/IHI0042E_aapcs.pdf)).  Then, the return address is popped from the stack into the PC - effectively ending execution of this function.  This implies that the instruction at `0x000083e0` is not a part of your program, and your inspection should be limited to instructions `0x000083c8` through `0x000083dc`.

So to answer your questions:

1. Correct.
2. <strike>The "instruction" at `0x000083e0` is essentially junk. You may not even have execution and/or access privileges to this memory depending on the specifics of your ARM core (Does it have an MMU, etc?).  Thus, a seg fault is a reasonable outcome when attempting to inspect that location.</strike>

EDIT: in agreement with comments below, the contents of `0x000083e0` should be interpreted as data, not instructions.

Comment: 0x000083e0 isn't really garbage. As it's content is loaded to R0 before calling puts, it should contain the address of the `"this is a test\n"` string

Comment: Correction: LR is not saved in R11. LR _and_ R11 (the frame pointer) are saved on the stack.

Comment: Also, `andeq r8, r0, r4, asr r4` is the 'disassembly' of the value 0x00008454. Now, what does that look like... ;)

Answer (score 2):

Four bytes at 0x000083e0 isn't junk. It is part of the PC relative load at

```
0x000083d0 <+8>: ldr r0, [pc, #8]    ; 0x83e0 <main+24>
```

It is also visible in the comment as `; 0x83e0 <main+24>`.

Problem here since you need to pass address of a string to `puts`, whose address might change during linking step, compiler needs to create suitable code for such further processing. Thus address of string ends up in instruction stream yet outside of any execution context.